# call require not possible in other file .js for nodeJs and express project

Tags: node.js, express

In project nodeJS - express, after install module by npm, when require "create-file" module in app.js const `cf = require('create-file')` , i can't use it in  main.js, in console i have this return `cf is not defined` when i run node.

app.js

```
`   const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cf = require('create-file');
// init app
const app = express();
//Template engine setup
app.set('view engine','html');
app.engine('html',ejs.renderFile);
// Index route
app.get('/',(req, res) => { 
res.render('index.html');
})
// Public folder setup
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
// Body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
//  Catch from submit
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
res.send(req.body);
})
// Define port
const port = 3030;
// Start server
```

const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log( 'Server start on port 
    3030 '));`

main.js

```
`const button12 = document.getElementById('button');
button12.onclick = function () {
cf('C:\Users\tmeda\Bureau\fileTest.txt', 'my content\n', function (err) {
// file either already exists or is now created (including non existing 
directories) 
 });
 }`
```

Comment: Why not require it one more time in main.js?

Comment: i can't, `require is not defined`

Comment: Try to edit your question and add your code, I think you are just missing something

Comment: @YouneL  pls have idea ?

Comment: You can not use create-file package on the client side, it's only available from the server, also the browser will not let you create a file for security purpose, the question is why you would create a file on the client machine ?

Comment: The job is:  - the customer introduces content and extension, receive the file genereted

Answer (score 0):

Define Your Variable as global in in your app.js file

like `global.cf = require('create-file');`

So this way you can access `cf` variable in any files , no need to require it again in different file .

Comment: `cf is not defined` when i try to use cf in main.js

Comment: minor spelling mistake , use `global` instead of globle

Comment: not working  and still same problem, it is possible to be because of the architecture of my project ?

Comment: `const express = require('express');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
global.cff = require('create-file');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine','html');
app.engine('html',ejs.renderFile);
app.get('/',(req, res) => { res.render('index.html');
})
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body);
})const port = 3030;
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log( `Server start on port ${port} `));`

Comment: use `npm i --save create-file`

Comment: use global.express , global.ejs , global.bodyParser instead of const